# Toast Is not being Displayed in The Android App , But first it was being diplayed then after two days it stopped

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toast

I am Very new to Android Programming.. I have listed my code below. `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml`. I have tried following solutions but to no avail.

1. using only `this`
2. using `getapplicationcontext()`
3. using `getbasecontext()`

---

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button text2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    final  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 

    text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())  {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

    }); // Disabling/Enabling Wifi Mechanism 

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it stopped? The app crashed? If yes, what does the logcat say? It's hard to help without the crucial informations, don't let us guess what happens...

Comment: Silly question, is your WiFi enabled when you try it? And `v.getContext()` would be an appropriate `Context` there.

Comment: That last comment is unnecessary at the moment and very difficult to read in a comment, anyway. Answer the first two comments for additional help

Comment: @codemagic  , The app works perfectly fine and it disables/enables the wifi on my android phone perfectly but the toast does not appear now whereas it was appearing like a day ago on my avd and android phone !

Comment: Is that everything that is in your `onClick()`? Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if it reaches that line?

Comment: MainActivity.this also does not work i had told before

Comment: @codeMagic hey this is a link i found , can you please explain it to me

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

Comment: @user2336315  check the link

Comment: @Razz check the link

Comment: It looks like if you disable notifications in the settings of the device in JB+, then toasts will not show either. That's interesting, hadn't seen that before.

Comment: what is jB+ ?  how can i view those setting and change if notifications are disabled?

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Try using the activity context rather than the application context. See this link for a more thorough description:

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)